# What is the negation of the Universal Conditional Statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

This being the UCS:

(∀x ∈ D)(P(x) → Q(x))

How would I negate the statement?
And how would I push this negation inside the formula as far as it would go?

Comment: Bear in mind $\forall x\in D(R(x))$ is equivalent to $\neg\exists x\in D(\neg R(x))$, so if you know how to simplify $\neg(P(x)\to Q(x))$ you can do this.

Comment: I don't know how to simplify that

Comment: Do you know $P(x)\to Q(x)$ is equivalent to $\neg P(x)\lor Q(x)$?

Comment: Yes those are the same

Comment: $(\exists x \in D)(Px \land \lnot Qx)$